# SQL import only different records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, import

So sorry if this has been answered before, but I cannot find an answer anywhere. I have a SQL database on server "A" that has had updates etc etc on it at the same time the same database is on server "B".

Now the issues is, some websites moved over sooner than others and those were being updated etc on server "B" while the other websites (maybe 2 or 3 weeks worth of signups) where being updated on server "A."

Question is, I can't do an import from server "A's" .bak file to server "B's" cause I lose all of server B's data. Anyway to only import data that is different to server "B" from "A?" Make sense?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Be a bit more specific. Is this as a SQL server admin, or do you mind running SQL on the tables? If the former, you need to grab the right bit of the TLOGs, otherwise you'll need to do an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert

Comment: I wouldn't say I am an admin but SQL 2008 R2 and I have full access to the database and Enterprise manager etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at `SQL Data Compare` and `SQL Compare` from RedGate. You could create a one-time script, but these tools really come in handy for situations like this.

It sounds like `SQL Data Compare` is the tool you need right now. It allows you to compare data between two databases (you can select individual tables) and synchronize them.  It's extremely useful when dealing with identity columns and constraints.

SQL Data Compare:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

SQL Compare:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Answer (score 3):

See also the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command for TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have used TableDiff.exe in the past to do this.  There is are some good articles on using it here:

- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/03/03/60125.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx